# Matlab - imread - the argument must be a string

Tags: matlab, imread

I'm trying to run `imread` on all the images in a folder. I have accomplished this task, but there is an error which says that my argument is not a string.

```
h_path = 'C:\Users\john\Matlab\train';
dirlist = dir('*.jpg');

for i = 1:length(dirlist)
    f_path = strcat(h_path,{'\'},dirlist(i).name);
    disp(f_path);
    I = imread(f_path);
```

The error happens on the last line. Also, the `disp` function prints out my path without any errors.

Comment: use `f_path{1}`. Also, I recommend using `fullfile(h_path, {dirlist.name})` outside the loop to create a list of filenames.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks, that worked easily. About your suggestion: is it concerning a performance hit doing file I/O in a loop? I understand it is better.

Comment: @john: For a better performance remove the `disp`, a for loop is totally fine here. You can use `profile` and you will notice that nearly all time is spend in `imread`. Loops are only critical when doing a huge amount of iterations with very simple tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is the `{'\'}`, not sure why you put a cell array here in. Simply using a char and your code works:

```
for i = 1:length(dirlist)
   f_path = strcat(h_path,'\',dirlist(i).name);
   disp(f_path);
   I = imread(f_path); 
end
```

As Oleg already mentioned, it is better practice to use `fullfile`, it's platform independent and avoids issues with duplicated file seperators.

```
for i = 1:length(dirlist)
   f_path = fullfile(h_path,dirlist(i).name);
   disp(f_path);
   I = imread(f_path); 
end
```